# Retrieving an array of children in Firebase using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase, children

I have a database which looks something like this:

Firebase
     restaurants
          McDonalds
               Menu Item 1 : burger
               Menu Item 2 : fries
               Menu Item 3 : drink
          KFC
               Menu Item 1 : chicken
               Menu Item 2 : mashed potatoes
               Menu Item 3 : drink
          Taco Bell
               Menu Item 1 : taco
               Menu Item 2 : burrito
               Menu Item 3 : drink

How can I retrieve a list of only the restaurant names (array or dictionary is fine), without their respective menu items?

the output would ideally look something like ["McDonalds", "KFC", "Taco Bell"], with an accessible index or key.

Comment: There are answers but the bottom line answer is, you can't. Firebase always returns key:value pairs. You are going to run into issues with your Firebase data structure - see my alternative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var ref = Firebase(url: "https://<yourApp>.firebaseio.com/restaurants/")

ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
    snapshot in
    var restaurantNames = [String]()
    for restaurant in snapshot.children {
        restaurantNames.append(restaurant.key)
    }
    print(restaurantNames)
})
```

restaurantNames will have the array you asked for. You are still receiving the complete restaurant objects from firebase, but just using their keys(names).

Comment: Just added it in, it does what I need it to do perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, you cannot just return keys. The structure in your question may present some challenges down the road as there's too much of a link between the textual data and the node names.

Here's an optional structure that separates everything out for easy query's.

```
restaurants
   restaurant_id_0
     restaurant_ref: restaurant_name_0
     menu:
       menu_id_0:
          name: Burger
       menu_id_1
          name: Fries
       menu_id_2
          name: Beer!
   restaurant_id_1
     restaurant_ref: restaurant_name_1
     menu
       menu_id_0:
          name: Roast Beef Classic
       menu_id_1
          name: Curly Fries
       menu_id_2
          name: Milkshake
```

and then the names

```
restaurant_names
   restaurant_name_0: McDonalds
   restaurant_name_1: Arby's
```

With this structure you are separating the string data from the nodes that hold the data which enables you to easily query for all restaurant names from the restaurent_name node. You can also query for which restaurants have a Burger on the menu. Even find the ones that offer a Milkshake.

I might even suggest breaking the menu's out to flatten the data further.

```
menus
   restaurent_id_0
     menu_id_0:
        name: Burger
     menu_id_1
        name: Fries
     menu_id_2
        name: Beer!
```

Either of these will work and one of the benefits with this structure is if Arby's decided to replace the Roast Beef Classic (oh no!) with the Roast Beef Max (oh yes!) you can just change the name component without affecting other data

```
/restaurant_id_1/menu/menu_id_0/name = "Roast Beef Max"
```

Comment: @JoeSloan Give that structure a try - it's a common design pattern for Firebase. If it helps, please accept my answer!

Comment: Hi Jay, could you explain the difference between your answer and Eirik Berntsen's below?  I was able to get the array I needed using his answer, but maybe there's an advantage to actually restructuring the database the way you suggested?

Comment: @JoeSloan Sure! Erik provided a fine answer. However, observing by .value returns everything in the node... everything. So if there are 1000 restaurants and they each have 25 items on their menu and suppose you store some other data within each node, that will return 1000 * 25 nodes and children (and children of children if there's other data). That can be a *lot* of data to process through. By [Denormalizing your data](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html), you are working with smaller chunks in a shallower structure. With Firebase, the flatter the better.

Comment: @JoeSloan Oh, and some other stuff: You cannot change a key, but you can change a value. It's generally not a good idea to use static text (restaurant name in this case) to name your keys; what if the name changes? If it's stored as a value then you can easily change it with a ref.setValue("new name"). And queries.... queries on keys are weird but queries on values are a snap. Bottom line is that it's usually best to disassociate your static keys from your variable data.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Jay that does make sense.  Thanks for the resources!

Comment: @Jay how can i retrive the names like `fries, burger in side the returents`

Comment: @Xcodian I am not sure I understand the question: those are the values from the key:value pairs stored within each menu_id. You could iterate over the children in restaurant_id_0 to get those. Perhaps you should start another question and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done by the approch below : -

```
func getDataSource()
{    
    let macdArray = ["Menu Item 1" : "burger","Menu Item 2" : "fries","Menu Item 3" : "drink"]
    let macdDict = ["McDonalds":macdArray]
    let kfcArray = ["Menu Item 1" : "chicken","Menu Item 2" : "mashed potatoes","Menu Item 3" : "drink"]
    let kfcDict = ["KFC":kfcArray]
    let tacobellDArray = ["Menu Item 1" : "taco","Menu Item 2" : "burrito","Menu Item 3" : "drink"]
    let tacobellDict = ["Taco Bell":tacobellDArray]
    let restaurentArray = [macdDict,kfcDict,tacobellDict] as NSMutableArray
    let restaurentDict = ["restaurants":restaurentArray]

    let parentDict = ["Firebase":restaurentDict] as NSDictionary

    print(parentDict.objectForKey("Firebase")?.objectForKey("restaurants"))

    let consolidatedArray = NSMutableArray()

    for var i = 0; i < restaurentArray.count; i++ {
        consolidatedArray.addObject(restaurentArray.objectAtIndex(i).allKeys)
    }

    print(consolidatedArray)
}
```

I have used the your data as static data, all you have to replace the data you are recieving from backend.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at this myself & while the whole fire base thing is brilliant, the tutorials were a little vague for me. Dinosaurs rah rah etc. Anyway, after spending ages fiddling with arrays to populate tableviews I'm starting to get it. Or maybe not? Dunno. But pretty sure you can just get the keys by observing event type childAdded and then snapshot.value which gives you the whole malark to iterate through and snapshot.key which gives you the individual keys one at a time: 
var boink = snapshot.key
MyboinkArray.append(boink)

Comment: https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-essentials-for-android--ud009 maybe this helps